# How do I set the Content-type in Joomla?

Tags: php, http, joomla, content-type

I am developing a Joomla component and one of the views needs to render itself as PDF. In the view, I have tried setting the content-type with the following line, but when I see the response, it is text/html anyways.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

If I do this in a regular php page, everything works as expected. It seems that I need to tell Joomla to use application/pdf instead of text/html. How can I do it?

Note: Setting other headers, such as `Content-Disposition`, works as expected.

Comment: I can confirm that it still works on Joomla 1.7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since version 1.5 Joomla has the JDocument object. Use [JDocument::setMimeEncoding()](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Document/JDocument.html#setMimeEncoding) to set the content type.

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMimeEncoding('application/pdf');
```

In your special case, a look at [JDocumentPDF](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Document/JDocumentPDF.html) may be worthwile.

Comment: Looks like that link to JDocumentPDF is dead. Apparently it was abandoned in framework v1.6. Here the old link is still alive: https://api.joomla.org/1.5/Joomla-Framework/Document/JDocumentPDF.html

Answer (score 1):

For those of you thinking that the above is a very old answer, I confirm that the JDocument::setMimeEncoding() still works, even on the 1.6 version (haven't tried it on 1.7 yet).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in joomla 2.5. After 8 hours of clicking around in the joomla admin panel I found a solution.

1. Log into your joomla admin panel and click on media manager
2. Click the options button in the top right hand corner. This opens a configuration tab with various options
3. In the box for legal file extensions, application/pdf or whatever you need. Values are separated by a comma.  *Note, apparently you have to list things in alphabetical order according to a forum I just found*
4. Click save button

You should now be able to load pdfs into media manager. Hope this works for you. I just set mine up to upload `.mov` extensions.

The problem is it only worked once. Now the browse link doesn't work whenever I navigate to a movie .mov file on my hard drive. But it does if I select any other file type ?